# How to parse integers in JSON file with a character following them (type marker)?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file which contains additional JSON data that follows the format below.

```
["{id:\"thaumcraft:celestial_notes\",Count:5b,Damage:10s}",
"{id:\"bloodmagic:ritual_stone\",Count:1b,Damage:0s}",
"{id:\"enderio:block_lava_generator\",Count:13b,Damage:0s}"]
```

You should notice that there are types appended to the numbers in the JSON.
How do I get Python to parse this without error (it thinks they are supposed to be strings)?

I cannot modify my JSON file as it is 50,000 lines long and will change dynamically from user to user.

I've thought up different ways to parse the string, but they all are inefficient or are not practical and dynamic (there is another structure that looks like this in the JSON data I will need to account for).

```
"{id:\"enderio:item_inventory_charger_basic\",Count:15b,tag:{enderio.darksteel.upgrade.energyUpgrade:{level:3,energy:5000000}},Damage:0s}",
```

The correct answer would end with the JSON loading correctly, e.g. parsing every string to look like this instead.

```
"{id:\"enderio:block_wired_charger\",Count:13,Damage:0}"
```

Comment: Could you put examples of what you've tried so far? Do you know for sure which fields you want to parse? What are the restrictions of the numbers? Could they be negative or float?

Comment: The numbers shoudn't be floats, but can be negative.
So far [this](https://hastebin.com/celedanetu.py) is my way of parsing the first structure.